# How to store results of eventListener as an object?

Tags: java, canvas, arraylist, vaadin

I have a few mouse events which I'm using to draw boxes on a canvas. I have created a BoundingBox class which contains a constructer and get-set methods containing x and y coordinates, width and height of the boxes to be drawn on the canvas. However, as I have several mouse events (I have only done mouseDown so far), I do not know how I should store them. My mouseDown event so far creates a Div on click, containing the x-y coordi, but no width and height yet as I have yet to be able to draw boxes. Note that I am using Vaadin framework, thank you!

Here is my mouseDown eventListener:

```
element.addEventListener("mousedown", event -> {  // Create a Div on Click

            Element boundingBoxResult = ElementFactory.createDiv();
            element.appendChild(boundingBoxResult);

            JsonObject evtData = event.getEventData();

            double xcoordi = evtData.getNumber("event.x");
            double ycoordi = evtData.getNumber("event.y");
            boundingBoxResult.setAttribute("data-x", String.format("%f", xcoordi));
            boundingBoxResult.setAttribute("data-y", String.format("%f", ycoordi));
```

BoundingBox class:

```
package com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components;

public class BoundingBox {

    private double xcoordi;
    private double ycoordi;
    private double width;
    private double height;

    public BoundingBox(double xcoordi, double ycoordi, double width, double height) {
        this.xcoordi = xcoordi;
        this.ycoordi = ycoordi;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }


    public double getXcoordi() {
        return xcoordi;
    }

    public void setXcoordi(double xcoordi) {
        this.xcoordi = xcoordi;
    }

    public double getYcoordi() {
        return ycoordi;
    }

    public void setYcoordi(double ycoordi) {
        this.ycoordi = ycoordi;
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(double width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(double height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

Will there be a better alternative (like storing them in ArrayLists) as I will have multiple boxes drawn in future which means I will have to have many coordinates saved. Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how are you using them later, but you could just store them in a variable in parent class (i.e. where you add the listener). Something like:

```
List<Element> results = new ArrayList<>();

// ...

element.addEventListener("mousedown", event -> {  // Create a Div on Click
        Element boundingBoxResult = ElementFactory.createDiv();
        results.add(boundingBoxResult)

        // ...
}
```

Then the list lives as long as your parent instance (also a div?) does. Remember that if you are having your own bookkeeping of the elements like this, you might also need to clear that at some point.